# how to add domainuser to TFS 2012 server?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2012

I am currently trying to add a user to the 'Admininster your server' page in the security/users section for tfs 2012 server. The user that I would like to add is in the same domain the tfs server is in. How can I add this user because it does not show up in the user search section?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to give access to this user for specific Team Project/Collection, you can do this through the Group Membership in Either Team Explorer or Web Access.

For Complete Admin Permissions (all Collections and Projects) use the following screenshot.

[image: Add User To TFS Administrators]

Or If you want to grant TFS Groups level please find the below screenshot using TFS Administrator Console:

[image]

Comment: :how can I add a user to a tfs group?

Comment: You can do that through the second screen shot.
open the TFS Console Admin, navigate to the Application Tier Node.
on the right hand you will find 'Administer Security' that will pop up the dialog in the picture.

you can then choose which TFS group you like to add the user to and double click on it. then select either TFS User or Windows User and choose the user you want.

then it will be added to the desired group.